# Get response message from WSDL in Savon without making a request to a service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, wsdl, savon

I would like to get the service, operations and per operation the request and the **response messages** from a wsdl file. This without making an actual call to a webservice.

I managed to get the service, operations and the request messages but the response is a problem.

Using Savon 2 I can retrieve the request by doing.

```
client = Savon::Client.new(....)

def get_request
  // list of operations can be found using client.operations
  ops = client.operation(:action_name_here)

  // build the body of the xml inside the message here        
  ops.build(message: { id: 1, name: "User", age: 30 }).to_s
end
```

But how can i get the response (example) from the wsdl ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to test your code? Then you should look into fixtures.

Comment: Say i have a wsdl but no service. I want to create a service based on the wsdl.